# Why I cannot connect to MongoDB from outside while I have set its IP to 0.0.0.0 with no firewall?

Tags: iptables, ufw, telnet, traceroute

First `netstat -nltp` output displays:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1235/mongod
```

So it seems that MongoDB is running on port `27017` and accept connection from all `IPs`.

Just to make sure `MongoDB` is up and running I issued `mongo` command to make sure I can see mongoDB:

```
mongo --port 27017 -u "MyUser" --authenticationDatabase "admin" -p 'MyPassword'

MongoDB shell version v4.2.8
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("00000000-d8c3-422a-9446-38eb624dd88f") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.8
```

Now I tried `tcptraceroute` command to make sure nothing in between closes my connection:

```
$ sudo tcptraceroute My-Server-IP-Address 27017
Password:
Selected device en0, address 192.168.1.55, port 54871 for outgoing packets
Tracing the path to My-IP-Address on TCP port 27017, 30 hops max
 1  192.168.1.1  8.847 ms  3.853 ms  0.994 ms
 2  * * *
 3  10.101.96.93  26.486 ms  24.977 ms  27.186 ms
 4  10.101.105.14  41.399 ms  30.886 ms  16.155 ms
 5  * * *
 6  10.101.97.57  24.635 ms  29.538 ms  17.545 ms
 7  10.101.117.25  39.587 ms  47.088 ms  62.840 ms
 8  * * *
 9  10.21.251.106  29.101 ms  29.739 ms  34.785 ms
10  10.21.21.22  35.107 ms  19.941 ms  20.011 ms
11  10.21.211.20  49.572 ms  33.257 ms  34.870 ms
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  ex9k1.dc5.fsn1.A-DOMAIN.com (AN-IP-ADDRESS)  93.807 ms  108.962 ms  115.046 ms
15  static.ANOTHER-IP.clients.your-server.it (IP-ADDRESS-IT)  99.938 ms  102.719 ms  109.238 ms
16  static.MY.IP.ADDRESS.clients.your-server.de (MY.IP.ADDRESS) [closed]  173.753 ms  112.972 ms  102.902 ms
```

On last hop I see `[closed]` flag.

---

**To list all server firewall rules:**

```
$ sudo iptables -L -n 
-> # sudo iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:80

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-after-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

And lastly my `telnet` output:

```
$ telnet MY-IP 27017
Trying MY-IP...
telnet: connect to address MY-IP: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

What I have done wrong? What should I do to connect to `MongoDB` from outside?

---

EDIT:

By changing port from 27017 to 27018, I could connect to `MongoDB` and everything works fine. But I'm still curious why I cannot use 27017 port and what I have done wrong in `iptables` configuration?

**NOTE:** ufw firewall is disabled.

Comment: please use a linux box from outside and do `nmap -sT -Pn <mongoIP>` and add this to your question. Also `sudo iptables --list-rules` and `sudo ufw status verbose`

Comment: `nmap -p 27017 the-ip` is your friend. If you can't use 27017/tcp probably it's because is already used. Check with `ss -tlp`

Answer (score 2):

Does "from outside" refer to general web, as in behind your router/firewall?

As this sounds as if your firewall/router is blocking it. I am not refering to OS firewall, but your physical firewall.

You should check if you have policies setup to allow outside connections, as well as configuring NAT (port forwarding) on your router.

Comment: I do not have physical firewall. By `from outside` I meant outside of the server as I can connect to Mongo from within the linux server itself. It also contacted the server provider and they told me it is from the linux server itself we do not have any firewall in between.

Comment: I now see that you said that Mongo listens on all IPs, but could it be that it's config was actually set with wrong BindIp ? I found Mongo quite picky with BindIp format, perhaps try setting back 27017 and enter just local IP 192.168.1.55 Likewise you say from outside the server so you can't reach it from LAN IPs in 192.168.1.0/24 subnet either? Because your traceroute certainly goes outside, so was your client accessing from "Internet" or from local net? Access from some PC eg 192.168.1.11 should have just one hop in traceroute, straight to 192.168.1.55. I'd say you changed something else

Comment: Please also check my last edit in question, I resolved the issue by changing port to `27018`. So it seems `27017` is blocked somehow in iptables?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that edit, but it makes no sense. Are you sure only change you did was that one number in that once config and then it all worked? As I'd be inclined some other change was also made just you didn't register it conciously. Did you try to change back to 27017 now that it works on 27018? As in don't touch anything else. Naturally, restart mongod service after the change to apply port change.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your ISP is blocking that port. Many use transparent proxies and other stuff.

Another is that you're using an antivirus Software in your client computer that does the same.

Or your router has activated dynamic ports or NAT, interfering.

Another possibility is that another process is listening into that port:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
```

This will tell you which process is listening in which port.
I saw your output only for one line, but it could happen that you have another process listening in that port with ip x.x.x.x and mongo listening in that port with 0.0.0.0, but will not do for x.x.x.x.

You can use also:

```
sudo ss -tunlp
```

If Mongo is listening in the right port, then run tcpdump to know if your computer gets to there.

```
sudo tcpdump | grep $YOURIP
```

Where $YOURIP is the Ip of the client machine, so your workstation.

You run tcpdump and then attempt a connection. If you don't see anything, something is blocking the connection.

Knowing if Mongo is listening in the right port and if the packets are arriving is the first thing I would try.